# Forcing 'who' utility to use date format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" [LC_TIME]

Tags: linux, locale

How to force 'who' core utility to use "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" date format?
I have tried modifying my LANG, LC_ALL, LC_TIME, but none of them produced the required result.
I have manged to get it working on by the following command:
env -i ssh me@remotemachine 'who -s'

Well in this case SSH didn't send my LANG and LC_* variables to the remote machine.

Let's look at 'who' utility source code:

```
if (hard_locale (LC_TIME))
    {
      time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M";
      time_format_width = 4 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2;
    }
  else
    {
      time_format = "%b %e %H:%M";
      time_format_width = 3 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2;
    }
```

Well, I need this to on Linux and Mac OS X (BSD), but 'who' behaves identically on both. hard_locale() code is right here: http://opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-81/sort/hard-locale.c

It checks LC_TIME and if it's "C" or "POSIX" it's not hard locate, in that case it's free not to use any locale.

Setting:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
export LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Does not modify the date format on 'who' output.

Another interesting observation:

```
# 2012-01-13 13:56 is used on remote machine (en_US.UTF-8)
# Now let's do this:
# env -i ssh me@remotemachine 'who -s'
# Jan 13 14:33 is used on remote machine
```

Any ideas? Or maybe setting variables is not enough?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a wrapper which reads the date into a date object in a lib that can export in the system locale. Should be easy because the output of who is very predictable.